# List distinct column values where those rows share other column values

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a query to detect possibly-invalid data in a PostgreSQL table. We have a table of city names like this:

```
# `city_names`
id    | name     |   language | dialect | city_id
------------------------------------------------
01    | London   |   A        | A1      | 1
02    | London   |   A        | A2      | 1
03    | London   |   B        | B1      | 2
04    | London   |   B        | B2      | 3
```

In our domain:

- It's fine that rows 01 and 02 both map "London" to city 1; the dialects don't happen to differ
- It's fine that row 03 maps "London" to city 2; in that language, the name may refer to a different city
- It's suspicious that row 04 maps "London" to city 3, because we already have a mapping to city 2 in the same language

I want to write a query that selects only rows 03 and 04 so that a human can decide whether one of them points to the wrong city.

I can solve this problem procedurally, but I'm having trouble doing it in SQL. For example, if I `GROUP BY` language and name, I lose the `city_id` values from the individual rows.

Basically my goal is: **"If there's more than one city_id for the same name and language, list those city_ids."**

How can I do this?

Comment: A procedural solution is: make a hash. For each row, ensure the hash has a key with its name and language, like "London-A", and a value for the set of all city_ids matching that. Insert the row's city id. At the end, list the hash keys where the set has more than one item. (Of course, this is horribly slow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do. The trick is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT city_id)`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/b5626/2)

**PostgreSQL 8.3.20 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("id" int, "name" varchar(6), "language" varchar(1), "dialect" varchar(2), "city_id" int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("id", "name", "language", "dialect", "city_id")
VALUES
    (01, 'London', 'A', 'A1', 1),
    (02, 'London', 'A', 'A2', 1),
    (03, 'London', 'B', 'B1', 2),
    (04, 'London', 'B', 'B2', 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.*, d.dups
FROM table1 t INNER JOIN
(
  select name, language, count(distinct city_id) as dups
  from table1
  group by name, language
  having count(distinct city_id) > 1
) d
ON t.name = d.name and t.language = d.language
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/b5626/2/0)**:

```
| ID |   NAME | LANGUAGE | DIALECT | CITY_ID | DUPS |
|----|--------|----------|---------|---------|------|
|  3 | London |        B |      B1 |       2 |    2 |
|  4 | London |        B |      B2 |       3 |    2 |
```

Comment: Awesome! I ended up changing this slightly to create a temporary table `suspicious_city_names` for the inner query, then join to it. I think this makes the query a bit easier to follow. Thanks for your help!